# Inserting cells into worksheet and row specified by a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I am desperately looking for help with my VBA code. My question is quite detailed and particular, so I decided to pose it as a comment in the code. If such a conduct makes my question blurry or vague, polease let me know.
In brief my code cpoies a line (from "FSR" workbook) that fullfils the criteria and pastes it into a particular worksheet and particular row (given by values o "P" and "Q" columns in "FSR" worksheet). What I need more is to insert cells (and shift existing cells down) into the same place where my code pastes copied cells, but before it pastes them there. I need to insert cells into the columns A:J and into the row given by the value in column "G" in Worksheet("FSR"). I need to place this new code into the FOR loop because this inserting, as well as copying and pasting needs to be looped.
And now code with questions in comments:

```
Sub FromSOF()
Dim Worksheet As Worksheets
startrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(10, 1)
endrow = Worksheets("GUTS").Cells(11, 1)

For x = startrow To endrow
    If Cells(x, "O").Value = "P" Then
        Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Select 'And here is the porblem. This one and three consecutive lines are to insert cells and shift the existing cells down. The cells need to be inserted into the worksheet given by the value in column "P" in Worksheet("FSR") and into the row given by the column "Q" in Worksheet("FSR")
        Range("A" & Worksheet("FSR").Cells(x, "P").Value, "J" & Worksheet("FSR").Cells(x, "P").Value).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Worksheets("FSR").Select
        Range("E" & x, "H" & x).Copy
        Worksheets(Cells(x, "P").Value).Cells(Cells(x, "Q").Value, "C").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank You all in advance!
I hope that my struggle with the code will end due to Your courtesy
withe best regards
Artur Rutkowski

Answer (score 0):

Code below will create a and copy data to it:

```
'Create line
Worksheets(Worksheets("FSR").Cells(x,"P").Value).Rows(Worksheets("FSR").Cells(x,"Q").Value).EntireRow.Insert
'Copy data (without clipboard)
Range("E" & x, "H" & x).Copy Worksheets(Worksheets("FSR").Cells(x,"P").Value).Cells(Worksheets("FSR").Cells(x,"Q").Value,1)
```